# Running a Javascript file (Adsense) after page load

Tags: javascript, onload, adsense

I'm trying to run Adsense after the page has loaded. But inserting the Adsense script file into an element doesn't seem to run it. Here is the version without `window.onload` (I modeled it after the Analytics script):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// adsense variables
google_ad_client = "my-pubid";
google_ad_slot = "my-adslot";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
(function() {
    var ad = document.createElement('script');
    ad.async = true;
    ad.src = 'http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js';
    var s = document.getElementById('ad_top');
    s.appendChild(ad);
})();
</script>
```

The onload version is the same, just wrapped in `window.onload`. Checking Chrome dev tools, the **script is inserted** in the `#ad_top` div but **no ads show**. I've tried moving the variables to the very top of the page and it still doesn't display even though the script is inserted fine.

Note: I'm not interested in loading it inline at the bottom of the page and moving it (as in an answer to a related question), I don't want to start loading anything until after the page has fully loaded.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the only difference is `(function() {` is replaced by `window.onload = function() {` and `})();` is replaced by `};`. But *neither* version works so I thought it was irrelevant.

Comment: Ah, somehow I had the impression the code you quoted was working.

Comment: Hmm, I tested with a basic JS file with an alert, and that worked OK so I guess it's some problem with the Adsense JS itself. It must be running, but not loading the ads.

Comment: Adsense js file adds ads onload, if you add adsense js onload then the  js file won't have any event to attach ads, you have to carry over the event